# ¿Cómo usar el mismo usuario del CLI para el Web Server?

Tags: php, apache, docker

Tengo una aplicación de Symfony con Apache como web server dockerizada. Al intentar pasar a producción me encontré con problemas de permisos de escritura. Intenté seguir la [documentación de Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html#2-use-the-same-user-for-the-cli-and-the-web-server) pero no sé como implentar este método.

Adicionalmente tengo un `start.sh` para arrancar la app:

```
//Dockerfile
FROM php:8.1-apache
...
CMD ["./start.sh"]

//start.sh
#!/bin/bash
...
apache2-foreground
```

Comment: Symfony necesita poder escribir sobre algunos directorios (var/cache, var/logs). Depende si están montados desde el host o son parte de la imagen cuál puede ser la mejor solución

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Si, además de eso hay que crear un nuevo usuario y grupo y asignarlo a esas carpetas (y cualquier otra carpeta que requiera guardar archivos como imagenes ect.) y al web server.

Answer (score 0):

Solución: Crear un nuevo usuario y grupo y asignarlo a los directorios `var/cache` y `var/logs` y al web server.

```
//Dockerfile
RUN adduser -q newuser //Crear usuario y grupo
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER newuser //Variable global que utiliza apache para definir su usuario
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP newuser //Variable global que utiliza apache para definir su grupo
RUN chown -R ${APACHE_RUN_USER}:${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} var/ //Asignamos el usuario y grupo
//a los directorios
```

También hay que asegurarse de que los directorios ya mencionados existan

```
RUN mkdir -p var/log && \
    mkdir -p var/cache
```